# Shifter cable. VW New Beetle 1998

Tags: vw, shifting, beetle

How do I physically put my 98 VW Beetle into 3rd gear?  The shifter cable  broke and I need to put my car in my garage and can't push it up hill.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This linkage is between the airbox and the engine ontop of the transmission.

Turn the linkage one way then the other, then put it in the between the two extremes to find (neutral). Then press down and turn counterclockwise that will be 1st gear.

If you want a higher gear from there second is hold down and full clockwise.
If you are going to be going uphill I don't suggest third gear or higher.